# Flex Facebook application doesn't show on webserver

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, facebook

I'm currently learning to make facebook apps with Flex from here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt3.html

I've done step 6 in "Upload the application to your web server" section which is to upload the Flex files in bin-debug folder via FTP and run it, but the facebook apps just doesn't show on the webserver I use. here is where I uploaded the files: 
http://cobacoba.netai.net/facebook/denishere/

I can't locate the problem, is it because the webhosting or what?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web server or domain is currently being blocked or redirected to elsewhere.  Most likely this is being done by your web host.  You should contact them and ask about any problems with your site.

Answer (score 0):

i did used the same link to develop ma facebook-flex interface,

I am sahring the code with you,

do use atleast flex3.5, if u r working on flex3, this will not work, and yes, developing an air application is much easier, that doesn't even need web support, but developing a web app requires, requires a web server, you won't be able to check the facebook app on your local machione, you have to upload it to the web server, then only it'll work

i have this code , thats works,

```
<mx:Script>         <![CDATA[           import com.Global;          import com.PMSocial;            import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;           import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
                    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;          import mx.controls.Alert;           import mx.controls.ToolTip;             import mx.managers.ToolTipManager;
                    protected var topURL:String=ExternalInterface.call('top.location.toString');            [Bindable]private var facebookPhotoAlbums:ArrayCollection;          [Bindable]private var facebookPhotos:ArrayCollection;
                    private var btn1Info:String="Click this button to log in to Facebook";          private var btn2Info:String="Logout";           private var btn3Info:String="Press this button, to get \n Album List in Drop down..";
                    protected function initApp():void           {
            Facebook.init("Your application ID",loginHandler);          } 

                    protected function loginHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void            {
            if(success){    

                Facebook.api("/me",getMeHandler);
                //userImg.source=Facebook.getImageUrl(success.uid,"small");
                Facebook.api("/me/statuses",getStatusHandler);
            } 
            else if(!success && !topURL){
                ExternalInterface.call("redirect","207419415939415", "user_birthday,read_stream,publish_stream","http://apps.facebook.com/flex-connectivity/");
            }

        }
                    /* protected function loginHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void             {
            if(success)
            {
                //currentState="loggedin";
                Facebook.api("/me",getMeHandler);
                //userImg.source=Facebook.getImageUrl(success.uid,"small");
                Facebook.api("/me/statuses",getStatusHandler);

            }           } */
                    /* protected function loginHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void             {
            if(success)
            { 
                currentState="loggedin"; 
                Facebook.api("/me",getMeHandler); 
                userImg.source=FacebookDesktop.getImageUrl(success.uid,"small");

                FacebookDesktop.api("/me/statuses",getStatusHandler);

            }           } */
                    protected function login():void             {
            Facebook.login(loginHandler,{perms:"user_birthday,user_photos,read_stream, publish_stream"});
            //Facebook.login(loginHandler,["user_birthday","read_stream","publish_stream"]);            }           public function logout():void           {
            Facebook.logout(logoutHandler);
            //currentState="loggedout";             }
                    protected function logoutHandler(response:Object):void          {
                        }
                    protected function getMeHandler(result:Object,fail:Object):void             {
            nameLbl.text = result.name;
            //birthdayLbl.text=result.birthday;
            getPhotoAlbums();           }
                    protected function getStatusHandler(result:Object, fail:Object):void            {
            //trace(result[0].message);
            //statusLbl.text = result[0].message;           }           protected function submitPost():void            {
            //Facebook.api("/me/feed",submitPostHandler,{message:statusInput.text}, "POST");            }
                    protected function submitPostHandler(result:Object,fail:Object):void            {
            //statusInput.text="";
            //Facebook.api("/me/statuses",getStatusHandler);            }
                    private function getPhotoAlbums():void          {
            var fql:String = "select name, aid from album where owner = me()";              
            Facebook.fqlQuery(fql, handleGetAlbumsResponse);            }
                    private function handleGetAlbumsResponse(albums:Object, fail:Object):void           {
            //Alert.show('handleGetAlbumsResponse : '+(albums==null)?"empty":"non-empty");
            if (albums != null)
                facebookPhotoAlbums = new ArrayCollection(albums as Array);
            else
                Alert.show("Error in albums");          }
                    private function showSelectedAlbum():void {
            var fql:String = "select pid,src_big, src_small from photo where aid = '" + albumCombo.selectedItem.aid + "'";
            Facebook.fqlQuery(fql, handleGetPhotosResponse);            }
                    private function handleGetPhotosResponse(photos:Object, fail:Object):void {
            if (photos != null)
            {
                facebookPhotos = new ArrayCollection(photos as Array);

                //Alert.show('facebookPhotos : \n\n\n'+JSON.encode(facebookPhotos));

                Global.facebookArr.removeAll();
                for each(var obj:Object in facebookPhotos)
                {
                    var o:Object = new Object();
                    o.imgCatId = "facebook";
                    o.imgSubCatId = obj.pid;
                    o.small = obj.src_small;
                    o.large = obj.src_big;

                    o.maxW = 400;       //default size is 400 X 500
                    o.maxH = 500;

                    o.available = false;
                    Global.facebookArr.addItem(o);
                }
                imagePage.dataProvider = Global.facebookArr;

            }
            else
                Alert.show("Error in photos");          }
                    public var myTip:ToolTip;           private function createBigTip(str:String,event:MouseEvent):void             {
            var p:Point = new Point();
            p = event.target.localToGlobal(new Point(event.target.parent.x,event.target.parent.y));
            myTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip(str,p.x+40,p.y+30,'errorTipBelow') as ToolTip;
            //myTip.setStyle("styleName", "errors");            }
                    private function destroyBigTip():void {
            if(myTip)
                ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(myTip);           }

                    private var exixts:Boolean;
                    private function submitFromFB(event:MouseEvent):void            {
            for each(var obj:Object in Global.facebookArr)
            {
                exixts = false;
                if(obj.available)
                {
                    if(Global.ImageArr.length>0)
                    {
                        for each(var o:Object in Global.ImageArr)
                        {
                            if(obj.imgSubCatId == o.imgSubCatId)
                            {
                                exixts = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(!exixts)
                        Global.ImageArr.addItemAt(obj,0);
                }
            }
            logout();
            PMSocial.remove();          }
                ]]>     </mx:Script>

<mx:HBox borderStyle="solid" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">       <mx:Button label="Login" click="login()" rollOver="createBigTip(btn1Info,event)" rollOut="destroyBigTip()" styleName="socialBtn" width="125" height="25"/>      <mx:Button label="Logout" click="logout()" rollOver="createBigTip(btn2Info,event)" rollOut="destroyBigTip()" styleName="socialBtn" width="125" height="25"/>        <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>       <mx:Label text="Welcome, " fontSize="13" fontFamily="Droid Sans"/>      <mx:Label id="nameLbl" text="Guest" fontSize="13" fontFamily="Droid Sans"/>         <!--<mx:Button label="3. Browse Photos" click="getPhotoAlbums()" rollOver="createBigTip(btn3Info,event)" rollOut="destroyBigTip()"/>-->         <!--<mx:Image id="userImg" top="171" width="50" height="50" left="10"/>-->  </mx:HBox>      <!--<mx:Label id="status" text="Status Message : Please log in" />-->   <mx:ComboBox id="albumCombo" textAlign="left" styleName="ComboBox11" prompt="Select Album" dataProvider="{facebookPhotoAlbums}" change="showSelectedAlbum()" labelField="name"/>        <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" paddingTop="3" verticalGap="0">         <mx:Label id="l1" text="Check images you want to upload, Please click on images you want to use" fontFamily="Droid Sans" fontSize="13"/>        <mx:TileList id="imagePage" height="100%" width="100%" 
                 columnCount="5" 
                 selectionColor="0xFFFFFF" rollOverColor="0xFFFFFF" 
                 rowHeight="150" borderStyle="solid" paddingBottom="-4">            <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <view:ManageClipart/>
            </mx:Component>             </mx:itemRenderer>      </mx:TileList>      <mx:Canvas width="100%">            <mx:Button id="submit" right="0" label="Submit" styleName="yesbtn" 
                   useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" click="submitFromFB(event)"/>             </mx:Canvas>
        </mx:VBox> </mx:VBox>
```

Hope it'll be helpful, alto this api really gives a huge amt of torture, haha, all the best